# What is going wrong with my Minimax Algorithm?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I tried to make a MiniMax AI using [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMLtza3CZFM),

The AI doesn't work and just goes on the bottom row and build up each time, reporting a column index of `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` and then for the next row and so on. The only thing I managed to find a lot different in the code output compared to mine and [the tutorials working version](https://github.com/KeithGalli/Connect4-Python/blob/master/connect4_with_ai.py) was the depth of the minimax algorithm as it goes along. Where [this](https://pastebin.com/9ZkgwgD7) was the depth of the working one as it recurred, and [this](https://pastebin.com/s6EK1r6F) was the depth of my one (it was longer than this but my console didn't keep all of it). I've tried a lot of things to get it working including reworking the board system to multiple lists inside a list and many other things like deleting some parts of the code and reworking scores but it doesn't seem to change.

My minimax function is:

```
def minimax(board, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer):
    print (depth)
    validLocations = getValidLocations(board)
    isTerminal = isTerminalNode(board)
    if depth == 0 or isTerminal:
        if isTerminal:
            if checkWin(board, computerDisc):
                return (None, math.inf)
            elif checkWin(board, playerDisc):
                return (None, -math.inf)
            else: # Game is over, no more spaces
                return (None, 0)
        else: # Depth is zero
            # print ("THIS IS DEPTH 0")
            return (None, scorePos(board, computerDisc))

    if maximizingPlayer:
        value = -math.inf
        column = random.choice(validLocations)
        for c in validLocations:
            boardCopy = copy.deepcopy(board)
            dropPiece(boardCopy, c, computerDisc)
            newScore = minimax(boardCopy, depth-1, alpha, beta, False)[1]
            if newScore > value:
                value = newScore
                column = c
            alpha = max(alpha, value)
            if alpha >= beta:
                break
        return (column, value)

    else: # Minimizing player
        value = math.inf
        column = random.choice(validLocations)
        for c in validLocations:
            boardCopy = copy.deepcopy(board)
            dropPiece(boardCopy, c, playerDisc)
            newScore = minimax(boardCopy, depth-1, alpha, beta, True)[1]
            if newScore < value:
                value = newScore
                column = c
            beta = min(beta, value)
            if alpha >= beta:
                break

        return (column, value)
```

And the tutorials function is:

```
def minimax(board, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer):
valid_locations = get_valid_locations(board)
is_terminal = is_terminal_node(board)
if depth == 0 or is_terminal:
    if is_terminal:
        if winning_move(board, AI_PIECE):
            return (None, 100000000000000)
        elif winning_move(board, PLAYER_PIECE):
            return (None, -10000000000000)
        else: # Game is over, no more valid moves
            return (None, 0)
    else: # Depth is zero
        return (None, score_position(board, AI_PIECE))
if maximizingPlayer:
    value = -math.inf
    column = random.choice(valid_locations)
    for col in valid_locations:
        row = get_next_open_row(board, col)
        b_copy = board.copy()
        drop_piece(b_copy, row, col, AI_PIECE)
        new_score = minimax(b_copy, depth-1, alpha, beta, False)[1]
        if new_score > value:
            value = new_score
            column = col
        alpha = max(alpha, value)
        if alpha >= beta:
            break
    return column, value

else: # Minimizing player
    value = math.inf
    column = random.choice(valid_locations)
    for col in valid_locations:
        row = get_next_open_row(board, col)
        b_copy = board.copy()
        drop_piece(b_copy, row, col, PLAYER_PIECE)
        new_score = minimax(b_copy, depth-1, alpha, beta, True)[1]
        if new_score < value:
            value = new_score
            column = col
        beta = min(beta, value)
        if alpha >= beta:
            break
    return column, value
```

When mine didn't work I tried to make it as close as possible to the tutorials function but it still doesn't seem to work. What do I need to do so it works?

The full programs:
Mine: https://repl.it/@MyloBishop/Connect-4
Tutorials: https://github.com/KeithGalli/Connect4-Python/blob/master/connect4_with_ai.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The board is passed passed to your minimax function as a parameter *node*, but inside the function you use *board*.

Reference program:
def minimax(board, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer):

Your program:
def minimax(**node**, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer):

Your ***recursive*** minimax function is therefore not working as expected.

Edit:
To fix this replace *board* inside minimax with *node*  (don't change *node* in the function definition to *board*)

Edit 2:
Also check the function scorePos - you have a hardcoded *computerDisc* instead of using the function argument.

Edit 3: 
Additionally, other helper functions like isBoardFull() and isSpaceFree() should operate on the board copy, not the global variable.

Comment: Thanks for catching that however, when I switched it back it didn't change anything because "board" is also a global variable so inside the function it just used that. I think it is something stupid like that but unfortunately, it isn't that... Any other things?

Comment: Think about how recursion works.  You pass a variable, make a copy, and then call the function.  It is wrong to use the global variable.  Please check: https://repl.it/repls/AdeptSparseLink

Comment: Thanks for the help! I always thought it would prioritize the local variable before the global variable but I guess i was wrong, it works perfectly now!

Comment: Actually, it works but I think it runs slower than it should.. Is this to do with it being on Repl or is it to do with inefficient code somewhere?

Comment: Great stuff.  It might be because of Repl.  Perhaps you can run the model solution in Repl and compare.  Rule #1 of optimization is to measure first.